# What is wrong with my SQL insert formatting that c# is not executing it?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

```
            string first = user1.FirstName;
            string last = user1.LastName;
            string ticket = user1.Ticket;
            string age = Convert.ToString(user1.Age);
            string command = Convert.ToString(("Insert into [TicketingVoting].dbo.Registration1 (FirstName,LastName,Age,Ticket) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');", first, last, age, ticket));
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data source=(local); Database=TicketingVoting;User Id=****;Password=****");
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand insertdata = new SqlCommand(command, conn);
                insertdata.ExecuteReader();
                Console.WriteLine("Inserting Data Successfully");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Occur while creating table:" + e.Message + "\t" + e.GetType());
            }
        }
    }
```

> Exception Occur while creating table:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 
>   'Insert'.
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   Press any key to continue . . .

I am completely stumped as to why when I try to run  my program, I get a this exception thrown at me. The program as a whole simply is registering someone into a database with a unique 'ticket' attached to it. I can gather the data no problem and the connection to my database is created but I get a syntax error for my insert statement.

Comment: show your error message

Comment: Make sure that `string command = Convert.ToString(("Insert into [TicketingVoting].dbo.Registration1 (FirstName,LastName,Age,Ticket) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');", first, last, age, ticket));` spits out a valid command.

Comment: `ExecuteReader` is for reading. You're not reading, you're inserting. Try `ExecuteNonQuery` instead. Also, *please* use parameters rather than pasting strings together; you'll be vulnerable to SQL injection plus it'll die the first time it sees a surname like "O'Connor".

Comment: Missing )  at the end

Comment: What kind of values are you inputting? Do those contain ' characters?

Comment: I'll say it: you should be using [prepared statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx), not building these command strings yourself. You're putting quotes around values that are [hopefully] not all string types in your database table. Let the command preparer figure out if it needs to quote your values or not.

Comment: Was about that say that Cory :)
Example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try adding a semicolon to the end of your connection string.  Also, as someone else noted, you can set a breakpoint after the `command` string has been generated and hover over it to see what it came up with.  Copy and paste that into SQL Server Management Studio and see if it runs that way.

Comment: Just checked with a breakpoint and the string command is coming up null.... anybody know why? also the age variable is being reported as 0, not the number I put in

Comment: You've tagged your question MySQL. Are you *really* using MySQL? Because I don't believe it uses square brackets for identifier names, nor schema names like `[TicketingVoting].dbo.Registration1`. Are you actually using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Well, the string command can't be `Null` if you've got an error message that mentions the word `INSERT`. Did you put your breakpoint on the `string command = ...` line? Because you need to step one line further to see the result of that statement.

Comment: ' "(Insert into [TicketingVoting].dbo.Registration1 (FirstName,LastName,Age,Ticket) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');, Jared, Morton, 0, DYE4LPAU)" ' this is the value I am getting

Comment: Why is it wrapped in brackets? Are you sure your question contains the actual code you're running?

Comment: @Matt: It can't be. The `Convert.ToString()` line wouldn't compile. I assume it should be `string.Format()`.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I'm not assuming anything at this point!

Comment: Your resulting command `' "(Insert into [TicketingVoting].dbo.Registration1 (FirstName,LastName,Age,Ticket) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');, Jared, Morton, 0, DYE4LPAU)" '` does not look like a valid command.

Comment: OK so i figured out how to populate the database, can anybody see why the age would be populated as 0 instead of the inputted age

Comment: Believe it or not, but the syntax error is not the main problem with your code.  
The main problem with your code is that it's a security hazard, as it's an open door for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.  
You should **never ever** concatenate strings with user input to create SQL statements. Instead, use parameters like in Cory's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would rewrite this to follow some better practices and hopefully solve your syntax problem at the same time:

```
// leave your datatypes as-is, no conversions
string first = user1.FirstName;
string last = user1.LastName;
string ticket = user1.Ticket;
int age = user1.Age;

// property dispose of your sql connection and commands; 
// they implement IDisposable so you should be using a using

using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data source=(local); Database=TicketingVoting;User Id=****;Password=****"))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();


        SqlCommand insertdata = new SqlCommand(null, conn);

        insertdata.CommandText = "Insert into [TicketingVoting].dbo.Registration1 (FirstName,LastName,Age,Ticket) VALUES (@fname, @lname, @age, @ticket);"

        insertdata.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = first;
        insertdata.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = last;
        insertdata.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = age;
        insertdata.Parameters.Add("@ticket", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = ticket;

        insertdata.Prepare(); // prepare the statement
        insertdata.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("Inserting Data Successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception Occur while creating table:" + e.Message + "\t" + e.GetType());
    }
}
```

You will have to adjust the parameter types and character lengths to what they actually are in the Database.

Comment: I agree this is the better way to go. Though I suggest you fix your current code to understand why and where it's failing. Then use this.

Answer (score 1):

Is that your actual code?

```
string command = Convert.ToString(("Insert into [TicketingVoting].dbo.Registration1 (FirstName,LastName,Age,Ticket) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');", first, last, age, ticket));
```

For me, results in

> > No overload for method 'ToString' takes 5 arguments

```
string first = "Fname";
string last = "LName";
int age = 65;
int ticket = 45687;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("Insert into [TicketingVoting].dbo.Registration1 (FirstName,LastName,Age,Ticket) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');", first, last, age, ticket);
string command = sb.ToString();

//Using Convert.ToString() like your original code
string commandTwo = Convert.ToString(new StringBuilder().AppendFormat("Insert into [TicketingVoting].dbo.Registration1 (FirstName,LastName,Age,Ticket) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');", first, last, age, ticket));

//using string.Format()
string commandThree = string.Format("Insert into [TicketingVoting].dbo.Registration1 (FirstName,LastName,Age,Ticket) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');", first, last, age, ticket);
```

Comment: I assume OP meant to use `string.Format()` and not `Convert.ToString()`.